# Grouping, Sorting, Summing in an XML where there is no order

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML that generates a transaction file, it records entries from a Clubcard of how much was spent to earn points and the date it was done. There is no order that I can use as the same card number may appear further in the XML. What I would like is to get the XSL to find a card number (which I do not have a record of to use as an ID), put it in a `<td></td>` and show how much in total was spent, how much points were earned and what date it was done.

This is the XML...

```
<Root>
  <Events>
    <TicketEnd Date="2012-10-21" />
  </Events>
  <Ticket>
    <TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
    <TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
  </Ticket>
  <Events>
  </Events>
  <Ticket>
    <TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="0" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <ClubcardPoints Opcode="96" Function="28" SchemeNo="40" PromNo="0" CardNo="1042540000026" QualSpend="30005" PointSpend="0" Points="6" BonusPoints="0" PromCount="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="1" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="30005" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket>
    <TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="0" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000019" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <ClubcardPoints Opcode="96" Function="28" SchemeNo="40" PromNo="0" CardNo="1042540000019" QualSpend="24330" PointSpend="0" Points="4" BonusPoints="0" PromCount="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="1" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000019" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="24330" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket>
    <TicketStart Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="0" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <ClubcardPoints Opcode="96" Function="28" SchemeNo="40" PromNo="0" CardNo="1042540000026" QualSpend="30005" PointSpend="0" Points="6" BonusPoints="0" PromCount="0" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <Clubcard Opcode="96" Function="27" CardAcc="1" QualSpendInfo="1" SchemeNo="40" CardNo="1042540000026" PointsToDate="0" RedemptionValue="0" CustomerUpdateDate="000000" QualSpent="30005" Date="2012-10-22" />
    <TicketEnd Date="2012-10-22" />
  </Ticket>
</Root>
```

My XSL can only list the entries...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>Loyalty Sales</title>
      </head>
    <body>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
       <h1 style="color:blue;
                  margin-left:20px;
                  font-family:verdana;
                  text-align:center;">
        Customers Report</h1>
      <br/>
      <p style="color:red;
                margin-left:20px;
                font-family:arial;
                text-align:right;
                font-size:15px;">
        Store Report</p>
      <p style="color:green;
                margin-left:20px;
                font-family:arial;
                text-align:right;
                font-size:15px;">
        for Customer ABC</p>
      <br/>
    <table width="100%" border="3">
      <THEAD>
      <TR bgcolor="RGB(0, 204, 51)">
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Account Number</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Points</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Date</B></font>
      </TD>
      <TD width="25%">
        <font color="white"><B>Qualified Spent</B></font>
      </TD>
      </TR>
      </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Ticket/ClubcardPoints">
      <TR>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@CardNo" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@Points" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="@Date" /></TD>
      <TD width="25%"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@QualSpend div 100,'&#x52;#.##')" /></TD>
    </TR>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </TBODY>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have searched for examples but cannot find a scenario that has all these conditions and when put to a single XSL it fails.
Please help.

Here is the output file I would like to have...

```
<THEAD>
                <TR bgcolor="RGB(0, 204, 51)">
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Account Number</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Total Points</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Date</B></font></TD>
                    <TD width="25%"><font color="white"><B>Total Qualified Spent</B></font></TD>
                </TR>
            </THEAD>
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD width="25%">1042540000002</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">100</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">2012-10-22</TD>
                    <TD width="25%">R750.32</TD>
                </TR>
```

Comment: Hello! Would it be possible to show your expected output? I am not 100% what your grouping criteria is (i.e. do you want a total for all dates, or to group by dates). In particular will your XML have different card numbers in, or just one? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Tim C, The output file has been included above. Luckily the XML will only have one date so the date field is fine. The difficulty is to find every time a card number is entered, to group the total times it was used then sum up the total points and total spent. So I would like the total for each card's points and money spent as a single entry, currently it outputs every single entry and the page is too long. Also there are different cards used and I do not know what they are until they appear in the XML.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to total each card's points and spend, then you will need to group the cards by their card number. In XSLT1.0, you use Munechian Grouping for this. This means defining a key for your group

```
<xsl:key name="cards" match="ClubcardPoints" use="@CardNo" />
```

Then, to select each distinct card number, you look for **ClubcardPoints** which occur first in the group for their card number. This is done as follows

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="Root/Ticket/ClubcardPoints[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cards', @CardNo)[1])]" />
```

Getting the total points is then straight-forward

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cards', @CardNo)/@Points)" />
```

Here is the full XSLT (Note that I've simplified it to remove all the styling)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:key name="cards" match="ClubcardPoints" use="@CardNo"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
         <THEAD>
            <TR>
               <TD>Account Number</TD>
               <TD>Points</TD>
               <TD>Date</TD>
               <TD>Qualified Spent</TD>
            </TR>
         </THEAD>
         <TBODY>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Ticket/ClubcardPoints[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cards', @CardNo)[1])]"/>
         </TBODY>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ClubcardPoints">
      <TR>
         <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="@CardNo"/>
         </TD>
         <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cards', @CardNo)/@Points)"/>
         </TD>
         <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Date"/>
         </TD>
         <TD>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('cards', @CardNo)/@QualSpend) div 100,'R#.##')"/>
         </TD>
      </TR>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table>
   <THEAD>
      <TR>
         <TD>Account Number</TD>
         <TD>Points</TD>
         <TD>Date</TD>
         <TD>Qualified Spent</TD>
      </TR>
   </THEAD>
   <TBODY>
      <TR>
         <TD>1042540000026</TD>
         <TD>12</TD>
         <TD>2012-10-22</TD>
         <TD>R600.1</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>1042540000019</TD>
         <TD>4</TD>
         <TD>2012-10-22</TD>
         <TD>R243.3</TD>
      </TR>
   </TBODY>
</table>
```

Note that, in XSLT2.0, grouping would be done by using the **xsl:for-each-group** element.

Comment: Dear @Tim C, thank you for your advise, I will give it a try on my side and report back. I did try xsl:for-each-group but did not know its for XSLT2.0. Thank you

Comment: Dear @Tim C. Your advise worked out perfectly. Thank you so much.